# SYSDBA privileges of viewing users table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Is there anyway which would restrict sysdba from watching the users tables. It sounds ridiculous but we sort of need this functionality. We only want sysdba to act as administrator only, no peeping into user's tables. Is it possible?

Comment: That is far from ridiculous; many cases where DBAs caused all sorts of problems, including one oil company's DBA changed the coordinates of new wells to explore, causing the company to spend millions on bad data.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Oracle Database Vault was made for.

http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/database-vault/overview/index.html

Note that, it is an extra cost option for Enterprise Edition.